# Amp optical in with stereo cable out

Tags: amplifier

I've got a tv in my outdoor area as well as some stereo speakers built into the roof. There are stereo cables which lead from the speakers to where the tv is.

I recently bought a budget amp which was Lepai Size: LP-2020A to get sound playing from the tv to the stereo speakers. (12V, 2A power supply. Specifications: Power output: 2 x 20 watts RMS ; )

Two things...

1. Unfortunately I learnt that my tv only has an optical out and the lepai doesn't have an optical in. The amp has only got RCA in and headphones in.
2. I tested the amp by playing music to my iphone through the amp to the stereo speakers and while the music played okay to the speakers at a decent volume, once I turned the amp up just pass 60% volume the sound in the speakers starts to break up. This makes me think that my amp was maybe not powerful enough.

Can anyone recommend me a fairly small not to expensive amp that might suit my scenario given the two points above?

Thanks

Comment: Same deal with my tv -> amp setup: I bought a cheap D/A converter, similar to [this on ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Optical-Toslink-Coaxial-RCA-Digital-SPDIF-Audio-to-2-RCA-Analog-Audio-Converter-/251938009020?hash=item3aa8acefbc:g:k3UAAOSweW5VP3Wv). Solid, metal housing. I bought it about 18 months ago, and never had a problem... *touch wood*.

Comment: 2. You need to check the speakers' specs to be sure. You could check them for damage too, being "built into a roof".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post that might help you [link](https://www.avforums.com/threads/budget-amp-with-optical-inputs.1591141/).

You could also buy an audio interface that works standalone with a volume Knob.
This one looks nice : [Esi Dr.DAC](http://www.thomann.de/fr/esi_dr_dac_prime.htm?ref=prod_rel_375160_1).
You only have to check if the volume is ok for you and also if works standalone.

Cheers,

Comment: thanks. I've bought myself a DAC today. Can't wait till it arrives int he mail for me to try